# Get array of json object and mapping to model class Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, object, model, mapping

I intend to map the output from external api to object attribute in model.

For examples, data->x to Device->$attribute_x;, data->y to Device->$attribute_y; The output is array of objects.

My expected outcome is extract each of object by access the Device model and its attributes and do some manipulation in model. (fetch once time only from API and format it in different function)

Can someone give some guideline on ways to defining methods/class to achieve?

This is my output from external API:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "x": "1",
            "y": "2"
        },
        {
            "x": "11",
            "y": "22"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is model without extend Eloquent in Laravel to extract all data from external API using guzzle .

```
namespace App;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
   'base_uri' => 'https://xxxx.com',
   'headers' => [
   'content_type' => 'application/json',
   'accept' => 'application/json'
   ]]);

$response = $client->get('units');
$data = json_decode($response->getBody());



class Devices
{
    protected $attribute_x;
    protected $attribute_y;

    public static function all(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write code from head, but you can create in Devices following method:

```
public static function importFromAPI($data) {

    $result = [];

    foreach($data as $item) {
        $dev = new Device;
        $dev->attribute_x = $item['x'];
        $dev->attribute_y = $item['y'];
        $result[] = $dev;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And use it to import Device list from data array from API json

```
$devices = Devices::importFromAPI($data);
```

Your `Device` can extend eloquent `Model` class as well to have easy access to DB. Above method can be also implemented in separate class e.g `ApiService` and be renamed to `importDevicesFromAPI` and contains code to load json and map it to Device objects.

Comment: `importFromAPI()` is a non-standard function, right? I was wondering why there is no common way for this common usecase?

Comment: @NicoHood - may be there is better, more reusable way. If you find better alternative please share with us in separate answer